# When i use columns lfor divide screen i cant see some navbar items

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello when i use navbar in col-6 area here is what i see
I searched some solutions but  i could not.Can you help me?Is it my fail or common problem?I have ever never seen problem like this before.
By the way I try to dont use columns and i try to create some divs side by side ,i couldnt do again
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlaMR.png

```js
window.onscroll = function () {
        myFunction()
    };

    var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
            header.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
            header.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }
```

```css
.top-container {
    background-color: #555;
    padding: 30px;


}

.header {
    padding: 10px ;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;

    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
    padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
    padding-top: 102px;
}

.nav-item {
    padding-left: 55px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>

        <div class="top-container text-white">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-telephone-inbound"
                        fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M15.854.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L11.707 5H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-4a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2.793L15.146.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0zm-12.2 1.182a.678.678 0 0 0-1.015-.063L1.605 2.3c-.483.484-.661 1.169-.45 1.77a17.568 17.568 0 0 0 4.168 6.608 17.569 17.569 0 0 0 6.608 4.168c.601.211 1.286.033 1.77-.45l1.034-1.034a.678.678 0 0 0-.063-1.015l-2.307-1.794a.678.678 0 0 0-.58-.122l-2.19.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1-1.657-.459L5.482 8.062a1.745 1.745 0 0 1-.46-1.657l.548-2.19a.678.678 0 0 0-.122-.58L3.654 1.328zM1.884.511a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 2.612.163L6.29 2.98c.329.423.445.974.315 1.494l-.547 2.19a.678.678 0 0 0 .178.643l2.457 2.457a.678.678 0 0 0 .644.178l2.189-.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 1.494.315l2.306 1.794c.829.645.905 1.87.163 2.611l-1.034 1.034c-.74.74-1.846 1.065-2.877.702a18.634 18.634 0 0 1-7.01-4.42 18.634 18.634 0 0 1-4.42-7.009c-.362-1.03-.037-2.137.703-2.877L1.885.511z" />
                    </svg> <span>Müşteri ve Sipariş Hattı <strong>0 342 321 05 19/20</strong></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6" style="justify-content: flex-end;">

                            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-person-plus"
                                fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                    d="M8 5a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zM6 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm6 5c0 1-1 1-1 1H1s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C9.516 10.68 8.289 10 6 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10zM13.5 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V7h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8h-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H13V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z" />
                            </svg> <a href="">Üyelik</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-box" fill="currentColor"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                    d="M8.186 1.113a.5.5 0 0 0-.372 0L1.846 3.5 8 5.961 14.154 3.5 8.186 1.113zM15 4.239l-6.5 2.6v7.922l6.5-2.6V4.24zM7.5 14.762V6.838L1 4.239v7.923l6.5 2.6zM7.443.184a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.114 0l7.129 2.852A.5.5 0 0 1 16 3.5v8.662a1 1 0 0 1-.629.928l-7.185 2.874a.5.5 0 0 1-.372 0L.63 13.09a1 1 0 0 1-.63-.928V3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .314-.464L7.443.184z" />
                            </svg> <a href="">Sipariş Takibi</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="header" id="myHeader">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <form class="form-inline bg-light">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><svg width="1em" height="1em"
                            viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search" fill="currentColor"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z" />
                        </svg></button>
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Ne aramıştınız?" aria-label="Search">
                </form>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText"
                    aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarToggle">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                                    class="bi bi-search" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                        d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z" />
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                        d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z" />
                                </svg><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link px-1" href="#">BAKLAVALAR <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link px-1" href="#">KURABİYE VE EZMELER</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link px-1" href="#">TUZLU FISTIK</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>



                    <a class="brand navbar-brand d-none d-lg-block" href="#"><img src="logo.png" width="200"
                            height="100" alt="Koçak Baklava"></a>



                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link px-1" href="#">ÜRETİMİMİZ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link px-1" href="#">BASINDA BİZ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link px-1" href="#">NEREDEYİZ?</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <div class="main-nav-toggle">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">



    </header>


    <div class="container-fluid">
        <img src="112-slider-jpg-slider (1).jpg" class="b-lazy b-loaded mx-auto d-block img-fluid" width="1600"
            height="670" id="girfot">
    </div>
    <div class="girmet">İstanbul ve Ankara’ya VIP Kargo ile 1 Günde Teslimat. <small>( Ertesi gün içerisinde teslim
            edilir. )</small></div>


    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2"></div>
                <div class="col-8" id="bilgi">
                    <h1 class="display-4" style="background-color: red;">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                        parent.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2"></div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2"></div>
                <div class="col-8" id="bilgi">
                    <h1 class="display-4" style="background-color: red;">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                        parent.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2"></div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to change there? and what is the core problem in your code?

Comment: When i divide screen for example col-6 col-6 , icant see my sticky navbar and navbar items